# X++ query to SELECT MAX value of String type field

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a field in Dynamics AX 2012 table populated with serial number of **PRE1 00162** format and I need to return next serial number, which in this case would be **PRE1 00163**.

On a legacy system it is achieved by running

```
SELECT MAX(RIGHT(SerialNumber,5))+1 FROM Table_Serials 
WHERE SerialNumber LIKE 'PRE1%'
```

against the table on SQL server.

How can I achieve same result in X++? My guess so far is

```
select maxof(right(SerialNumber,5))+1
    from tableSerials
    where tableSerials.SerialNumber 
like tableSerials;
```

but it shows syntax error starting right after `maxof(right(` part.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of my wise colleagues have also suggested this method, which also works:

```
static void CompNextSerial(Args _args)
{
    str value;
    int num;
    str 10 prefix;
    SerialsTable serialsTable;

    prefix = "PRE1 *";

    select firstOnly serialsTable
        order by SerialNumber desc
        where serialsTable.SerialNumber like prefix;

    value = subStr (serialsTable.SerialNumber, strLen(serialsTable.SerialNumber) - 4 , 5);
    num = str2int(value) + 1;
    info (strFmt('%1', num));
}
```

Comment: Better approach than view with `MAX(RIGHT(...))` (better performace, usability and readability, less complex approach). View is just rewrite of the legacy code.

Answer (score 4):

The right way should be to create [Number Sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa608474.aspx) ([Whitepaper](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=213124&clcid=0x409)).

---

If you relay want to keep legacy functionality you have to create AOT View with [**computed column**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg845841.aspx).
Example for the field `ViewMethod`:

```cs
private static server str compSerial()
{
    str srcCol = SysComputedColumn::returnField(tableStr(TableSerialsView), identifierStr(TableSerials_1), fieldStr(TableSerials, SerialNumber));
    str result = strFmt('MAX(RIGHT(%1, 5)) + 1', srcCol);

    return result;
}
```

And then add computed field to the fields of the view and select.

Comment: Thank you, Matej. I believe you brought me on the right path. 

So I got `str srcCol` part working, but when I'm trying to return `str result`, I'm getting _SQL error description: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Column 'TABLESERIALS.SerialNumber' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
_ 

The View of `srcCol` returns _Partition_, _RecId_, _CompNextSerial_, _SerialNumber_, _dataAreaId_ and _recVersion_ fields. 

Adding GroupBy field _SerialNumber_ didn't helped.

Comment: As you do in regular SQL, the field list in group by section has to be the same as the fields in select statement. Try to include this fields to the "Fields" node on the view to be coherent with the "group by" ones, like you do when building a regular SQL select statement.

Comment: Finally got it working. The problem was that I didn't chose **Aggregation** = **Max** for _SerialNumber_ field.

Comment: What about `LIKE 'PRE1%'` part? How to get it working in this view? Thank you, guys!